# Is there a way to write a funcion with async/await native?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, zonejs

I need to write a function that uses native async/await in Angular.

Example:

```
var function = () => {
    var _self = {};

    _self.test = async () => {
        return await someAsyncFunc();
    }

    return _self;
}
```

When I do `ng build --prod` the configuration optimizes it and uses zone.js and catch async/await to handle the changes.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Dirty solutions:

1. Make it a string with `` for example.
2. Declare some vars and then `.toString()` and replace with correct syntax before executing it. **(Actually in use)**

Anyone have a better/clean solution?

Thanks